Need Help on Appscript
function addbutton() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet and sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  // Get the values from the specified cells
  var dr_no = sheet.getRange('E6').getValue();
  var sku = sheet.getRange('E8').getValue();
  var item = sheet.getRange('E10').getValue();
  var quantity = sheet.getRange('E12').getValue();
  var price = sheet.getRange('E14').getValue();
  
  // Define the range where the data will be inserted (Row 17, Columns A to E)
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(17, 1, 1, 5); // Row 17, starting from Column A (1), 1 row, 5 columns

  // Set the values into the target range
  targetRange.setValues([[dr_no, sku, item, quantity, price]]);
}

i want to add where from populated data on row 17 to infinity. i want on the column F is a data from the result of D multiply by E. and so on.

Please [edit] to add a proper title. See [ask]

Calculating quantity * price
you can add this approach to your problem
var result = quantity * price;
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 6).setValue(result);

and find the next empty row starting from row 17 in column A
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var nextRow = lastRow >= 17 ? lastRow + 1 : 17;

Full modify script
function addbutton() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dr_no = sheet.getRange('E6').getValue();
  var sku = sheet.getRange('E8').getValue();
  var item = sheet.getRange('E10').getValue();
  var quantity = sheet.getRange('E12').getValue();
  var price = sheet.getRange('E14').getValue();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var nextRow = lastRow >= 17 ? lastRow + 1 : 17;
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, 5); 
  targetRange.setValues([[dr_no, sku, item, quantity, price]]);
  
  var result = quantity * price;
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 6).setValue(result);
}

Sample output

Reference
Operators
Note: Please review the result to confirm if it meets your expectations. If not, kindly provide your expected result so I can adjust my response accordingly.
